# ColladaLoader.js calculate animation length - three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, keyframe

How do I get the length, in seconds or frames of a colllada scene with keyframe animation from ColladaLoader.js?

ColladaLoader.js has this function in it, "function calcAnimationBounds" but I cant figure out how to implement it.

I've been using the ColladaLoader keyfame example as a reference, however this example explicitly has the time in seconds in the script - (which is 48).

function animate( timestamp ) {

```
            var frameTime = ( timestamp - lastTimestamp ) * 0.001;

            if ( progress >= 0 && progress < 48 ) {

                for ( var i = 0; i < kfAnimationsLength; ++i ) {

                    kfAnimations[ i ].update( frameTime );

                }

            } else if ( progress >= 48 ) {

                for ( var i = 0; i < kfAnimationsLength; ++i ) {

                    kfAnimations[ i ].stop();

                }

                progress = 0;
```